# Grunt Serve index.php instead of index.html

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I Scaffolded a project with yeoman. When I serve my project with grunt. Grunt will serve index.html but I want to serve index.php.

What do I need to configure in the grunfile to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Does the index.php file have actual php code in it? If it does then you will need to figure out a different way of serving the page. Or you could try something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php